# Pass variable to button vue js laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, post, axios, comments

I am trying to pass a variable (id) of a specific comment that's in a v-for to a button that's rendered into a blade syntax. I managed to post and get comments but i am currently trying to delete specific ones based on their id. I have been struggling on how to get it to work but i keep getting this errors

> "vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'id' of undefined"

and

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

Anyone got an idea on how to solve the issue?

Here is my html

```
<div class="media" style="margin-top:20px;" v-for="comment in comments">
                     <div class="media-left">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="media-object" src="http://placeimg.com/80/80" alt="...">
                       </a>
                    </div>
                     <div class="media-body">



                     <h4 class="media-heading">@{{comment.user.name}} said...</h4>
                         <p>
                            @{{comment.text}}
                         </p>
                          <span style="color: #aaa;">on @{{comment.created_at}}</span>

                         <p>
                         @{{comment.id}}
                         </p>
                           <button class="btn btn-default" v-on:click="deleteComment('@{{comment.id}}')">Delete comment</button>
```

And here is my vue script where i am trying to pass the id of the comment

```
const app = new Vue({
el:'#root',
data: {
    comments: {},
    commentBox: '',
    post: {!! $post->toJson() !!},
    user: {!! Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->toJson() : 'null' !!},
},

mounted() {
    this.getComments();
},

methods: {
    getComments(){
        axios.get('/api/posts/'+this.post.id+'/comments')
             .then((response) => {
                 this.comments = response.data
             })
             .catch(function (error) {
                 console.log(error);
             });
    },
    postComment(){
        axios.post('/api/posts/'+this.post.id+'/comment', {
            api_token: this.user.api_token,
            text: this.commentBox
        })
        .then((response) => {
            this.comments.unshift(response.data);
            this.commentBox = '';
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

    },

  deleteComment(id){
      axios.delete('api/posts/'+this.post.id+'/comment'+this.comment.id) 
            .then((response) => {
                this.commentBox = '';
                return 'delete successfull';
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            });
  },





enter code here
```

Comment: Use this.post[id] and this.comment[id] instead, as it stands your variable is not being used in the deleteComment function.

Comment: @Jake thank you for your fast reply. I tried that but i got these errors vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property '{{comment.id}}' of undefined" and "Cannot read property '{{comment.id}}' of undefined". I'm assuming its either the way i'm passing the variable to the button, or that the id is not recognised.

Comment: Are you sure your comment has an id to begin with ? What's printed when you `console.log(this.comments[id])` in your function ?

Comment: @Jake yes my comment has id, text, date, userid and postid which is the id of the post that the comment is attached to.

Comment: Is it normal that some of your axios calls are using '/comments' and others '/comment' ? How is your data structured ? comments.comment.id ?

Comment: @Jake getComments (.../comments) is the method to return all the comments where  postComment (.../comment) is responsible for adding one comment if that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `deleteComment` method you are specifying the id as `this.comment.id` but you haven't bound `comment` in your data object which is why you are getting the TypeError.

Also, you are passing the id as an argument to your deleteComment method so replacing:

`this.comment.id` with `id` should resolve the problem.

Comment: thank you so much!!!! now i can see the id when i debug the code. But im having an issue with my route. In my axios delete i have (api/posts/51/comment/5) which is what is expected but in my api route i have api/posts/{post}/comment{id} im guessing there's an issue here with the id? Does the rest of my rest delete method look okay to you? Im sorry im new to this

Comment: Looks like you would need to add another slash in the route between comment and {id}: ```api/posts/{post}/comment/{id}```

Comment: Oh im sorry that was a mistake here because i mistyped it haha. In my debug i get an 500 internal server error when i click the delete button. By the way i am passing that to an api route which leads to a controller where in there in a destroy function i delete the comment.